# NSPredicate to find all objects whose title key starts with a vowel

Tags: objective-c, core-data, nspredicate

I have a set of objects with a `title` property (a `NSString`). I want to retrieve all of those objects whose `title` begins with a vowel. I guess I could use an `NSPredicate` for each letter and combine them with a `NSCompoundPredicate`, but was looking for something more elegant.

Is there a way to combine `BEGINSWITH[cd]` with `IN` and pass a `NSSet` of vowels?

Is there a better option?

Creating a bunch of predicates and then combining them seems cumbersome and ugly.

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to use the admittedly verbose `NSCompoundPredicate`. I think it would be most pragmatic to just write one long format string.

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: 
  @"title beginswith[cd] 'a' OR "
  @"title beginswith[cd] 'e' OR "
  @"title beginswith[cd] 'i' OR "
  @"title beginswith[cd] 'o' OR "
  @"title beginswith[cd] 'u'", title];
```

Took me about 30 seconds with copy-paste.

However, I don't think this will perform very well. Perhaps you want to consider creating a derived property by adding a boolean attribute `startsWithVowel` and updating that in the setter of the `title`.

```
-(void)setTitle:(NSString)value {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"title"];
    [self setPrimitiveTitle:value];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"title"];

    BOOL result = // your vowel logic
    self.startsWithVowel = @(result);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a predicate with a regular expression:

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"title MATCHES[c] %@", @"[aeiou].*"]
```